# Cypher returning Boolean after checking whether relationship exist between two nodes

Tags: database, graph, neo4j, cypher

I want a Cypher to return 1 if there is a relation exist between two provided nodes or return 0 if there is null relationship between them.

here is one cypher that would find the relationship and return it, but I want one Boolean value against the result

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (n:Node {id: {parameter1}})-[r:someType]-(n:Node {id: {parameter2}}) RETURN r
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try this, it should return 1 if one or more relationships exist, and 0 otherwise.

```
MATCH (n:Node {id: {parameter1}})-[r:someType]-(m:Node {id: {parameter2}})
RETURN SIGN(COUNT(r))
```

Please note that I used n and m as identifiers for the two nodes to mark that they are not necessarily the same.

Comment: Yes Axel marking m & n differently is having good reason. Ok, that is wonderful reply, can we use this `count(r)` to count how many edges / relationships are there ?
I mean I also need to count the number of relationship in next cypher !

Comment: Sure, you an use count for that! My note about n and m was just because you used two times 'n' in your question.